# Intellij how can I set default debug port

Tags: go, intellij-idea

I am using the new Intellij-idea for Golang and was wondering how can I set a default debug port for it ? I know how to do it in Visual Studio code but not IntelliJ . I am using this for a backend app development so every time the port changes I have to also change it in the app and it gets tiring . Every time I debug I get a new random port . In VS Code you have a launch.json but Intellij does not have that .

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a custom debug configuration:

1. `Run | Edit configurations`
2. Click `+` button and select `Go Remote`
3. Name it `My Debug`
4. In the `Port` field, enter the desired port number
5. Click `OK`
6. `Run | Debug... | 'My Debug'`